# How to dynamically change the 'repeat' property of Polyline in Google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, repeat

This is the code to drawing a line on the map in Google maps v3:

```
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: lineCoordinates,
strokeOpacity: 0,
icons: [{
  icon: lineSymbol,
  offset: '0',
  repeat: '20px'
}],
map: map
```

});

The `repeat` property can help us to draw dashed line. But I want to change this property dynamically. Something like this:
`setRepeat('20px');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must re-assign the icons-property of the line, e.g.:

```
  line.set('icons',[{icon:line.icons[0].icon,
                     offset:line.icons[0].offset,
                     repeat:'50px'}]);
```